Mllflow server OKTA authentication
I am trying to setup OKTA authentication and I followed the example https://github.com/cloudacode/mlflow-oauth-sidecar/tree/main?tab=readme-ov-file
but all the users access the same area, it looks like that the application dose not get sent the user’s email address and creates an account for the Okta user
